# Firebird SELECT DATEDIFF query returns nothing

Tags: sql, eclipse, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Eclipse's "Database Development" perspective to run queries against a Firebird database. One particular field, `studydatetime`, is giving me problems.It's a timestamp field holding the date and time of a medical exam. I have a text file that holds only the date, and I need to match the two to fill in some blanks in the text file. But when I run something like

```
select datediff(day,1,'2017-07-26')  
from worklistdisplay  
rows 1;
```

I get nothing - not even a query with no rows. Even when I run something like

```
select datediff(day,'2017-07-01','2017-07-26')
from rdb$database;
```

I get the same result. The "Status" tab in the Eclipse results window says

```
(0 rows affected)
Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 25 ms.
```

But no results are returned.

I'm using the "Generic JDBC_1.x" connection type in Firebird, with driver file "jaybird-full-3.0.1.jar". The DB version is 2.5.4.

Comment: Assuming worklistdisplay is a table, what about something very simple like `select count(*) records from worklistdisplay`.  If that returns records, try it again without the alias `records`.  If that does not return records, try the queries in the question, but with an alias.

Comment: @DanBracuk `select * from worklistdisplay wd rows 1;`  returns records. So does the query you suggest.

Comment: That would leave the queries in your question, but with an alias for the function result.

Comment: @DanBracuk Still nothing - i.e. I tried `select datediff(day,'2017-07-01','2017-07-26') as number_of_days from rdb$database;` and got the same (no) result.

Comment: I get the same result as well using DATEDIFF in the WHERE clause; but that's probably a different question.

Comment: Try to install the [Firebird Eclipse Data Tools Platform plugin](https://www.lawinegevaar.nl/firebird/index.html) and see if it works, I haven't touched it in a few years, so it might not be fully compatible with recent Eclipse versions though. If you run into issues, please report them on https://github.com/mrotteveel/fbdtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast to date will help

```
 select datediff(day,cast('2017-07-01' as date),cast('2017-07-26' as date)) from rdb$database
```

this return 25

Comment: Thanks - I guess I had thought a string in this format would automatically get cast to a date when compared with a date.